# Setting Pyomo Constraints to list of values

Tags: pandas, pyomo

I have a minimization model where individuals are getting grouped by how they ranked a selection.

I would like the group sizes to be equal to 0,3,4,5. This is what I tried a series of "or" statements, but it didn't like that.

```
for title in Title:
    model.cons.add(sum(model.x[name, title] for name in Name) == 0 or
                   sum(model.x[name, title] for name in Name) == 3 or
                   sum(model.x[name, title] for name in Name) == 4 or
                   sum(model.x[name, title] for name in Name) == 5)
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: There is some [good advice on how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). My initial comments: "it didn't like that" is too vague. You need to show the exception raised.  Show a minimum reproducible example code (including imports).  Show the actual and expected results. Tag the question with 'python'.